# Where can I find a boatload of source files for stress testing source scanning systems?

Tags: search, test-data

I thought the Linux kernel would have a massive amount of SLOC but it isn't even making OpenGrok blink.  I know the question of the largest project has been asked but what collection of code is arguable the largest.  i would prefer either tar, gz, or a hub style place where I can script and point my subversion or git client.

Comment: reference to question about largest project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than just the kernel, why don't you grab the source packages for a whole distro?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some Linux and also some BSD distributions that keep all the sources of all the packages in a single sourcetree, especially in the embedded or special purpose space. [OpenSolaris](http://Src.OpenSolaris.Org/source/xref/) is managed in a similar way.